# Can't get second level woocommerce product categories only

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to get only my second level categories from a 3 depth category structure in woocommerce.

But it always returns the 3rd level aswell.

```
/**
 * Get second level cat
 */
function get_second_cat_level($parent_id) {
    $subcats = array();
    $args = array(
        'parent'       => $parent_id,
        'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
        'orderby'      => 'name',
        'show_count'   => 0,
        'pad_counts'   => 0,
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'hide_empty'   => 0
        );
    $cats = get_categories($args);

    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        $subcats[] = $cat;
        var_dump($cat);
    }

    return $cats;
}
```

I assume that `$parent_id` is the string id of the parent_category.
This is just crazy.

Answer (score 0):

As no one seems to have any solution for me, I will share one solution I used. But be carefull, this is very specific to 3 depth level category groups.

I created 2 functions : 
one to get the category object from the id, the slug or the name of the given category :

```
function get_product_category($field, $value) {
    $authorized_fields = array(
        'term_id',
        'name',
        'slug'
    );
    // Check if field and value are set and not empty
    if (!isset($field) || empty($field) || !isset($value) || empty($value)) {
        $response = "Error : check your args, some are not set or are empty.";
    }
    else {
        // Check if the specified field is part of the authorised ones
        if (!in_array($field, $authorized_fields)) {
            $response = "Unauthorised field $field";        }
        else {
            // init exists var to determine later if specified value matches
            $exists = false;
            $product_cats = get_terms('product_cat', array(
                'hide_empty' => 0,
                'orderby' => 'name'
            ));
            // the loop will stop once it will have found the matching value in categories
            foreach ($product_cats as $product_cat) {
                if($product_cat->$field == $value) {
                    $response = $product_cat;
                    $exists = true;
                    break; 
                }
            }
            if ($exists == false) {
                $response = array(
                    "message" => "Error with specified args",
                    "field" => "$field",
                    "value" => "$value"
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $response;
}
```

The second function uses the first one to return the 2nd level categories. It uses an argument `$dep` which, when is tested alone as false, returns another result which I needed somewhere else. So don't pay attention to it.

```
function get_first_child_cat_only ($cat_id, $dep = true) {
    // Array which handle all the 2nd child sub cats
    $subcats = array();
    // $cat_id is the parent (1st level) cat id
    $categories = get_term_children( $cat_id, 'product_cat' ); 
    foreach ($categories as $sub_category) {
        if ($dep == true && get_term_children( $sub_category, 'product_cat' )) {
            $subcats[] = get_product_category('term_id', $sub_category);
        }
        elseif($dep == false) {
            $subcats[] = get_product_category('term_id', $sub_category);
        }
    }
    return $subcats;
}
```

Little explanation : the above function return only sub catégories which has categories children. So it ignores the last (3rd one) which have no children and returns the second one only.

This can certainly be improved, and I know I'll probably get some "criticisms" and actually, I hope so ! So don't hesitate :)